# Illegal attempt to exit early in Netbeans 8 form designer

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt, netbeans-8

I'm mystified by Netbeans being unable to render a form in the graphical designer. When I run the application, the window and components display just fine, like so:

[image]

However, trying to display the same window in the designer results in:

[image]

I have not been able to pinpoint the problem, especially given that the program works when run. What gives?

EDIT: Code suspected of being at fault.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    log.trace("Painting...");
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.0f)); // hairline

    AffineTransform transformer = new AffineTransform();
    transformer.scale(scale, scale);

    g2.setTransform(transformer);

    // TODO: Actual selection using the combobox in the frame.
    Collection<GravPoint> list = null;
    for (StarSystem s: GameState.inst().systems) {
        if (list == null)
            list = s.getCelestialObjects();
    }

    // Get the largest orbit.
    double maxOrbit =1;
    for (GravPoint gp: list) {
        if (gp.getOrbit() > maxOrbit)
            maxOrbit = gp.getOrbit();
        //log.debug(gp.getName() + " " + gp.getOrbit());
    }
    //log.debug("maxOrbit = "+maxOrbit);

    double x, y;
    double orbit;
    for (GravPoint s: list) {
        // TODO: urgh, can't this draw double-coordinates?
        // center.
        // The orbital path.
        orbit = 200*s.getOrbit()/maxOrbit;
        g2.drawOval((int)(center.x/scale)-(int)orbit+1,(int)(center.y/scale)-(int)orbit+1, (int)orbit*2, (int)orbit*2);
        // The body.
        x = center.x/scale + 200*s.getX()/maxOrbit;
        y = center.y/scale + 200*s.getY()/maxOrbit;
        g2.drawOval((int)x, (int)y , 3, 3);
        // The label.
        g2.drawString(s.getName() + "("+(int)x+","+(int)y+")", (float)x+10, (float)y+10);
        g2.drawString("x" + "("+center.x+","+center.y+")", (float)(center.x/scale), (float)(center.y/scale));
        log.trace("Printing "+s.getName()+" at "+s.getX()+","+s.getY());
    }
    log.trace("Done painting.");
}
```

Comment: The form designer preview will run your code, if you have a System.exit call, it may interfere with it, as it could force the current jvm to exit

Comment: @MadProgrammer: It's very strange, because the preview rendering problem disappears if I remove a custom JPanel from the tabbed pane, but within than custom JPanel, I do not call anything remotely like a system exit call. At least not explicitly. Perhaps the problem could be removed if I could stop the JPanel's custom draw routines from being run in the preview? (Don't know how, though.)

Comment: Without any code, it's impossible to know

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I've edited in the code I suspect to be causing this. When I comment it out, the preview rendering manages not to crash.

Comment: What happens if comment out the paint method?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Like I said, it doesn't crash. It prints the otherwise empty JPanel component in the JTabbedPane in the JFrame. This is mildly useful in of itself, because it allows me to modify the form while the method is commented out, then uncomment it to run the application. But it seems like a crude workaround.

Comment: It's possible that some stateful information that the paint method requires is not available and Netbeans is capturing the "crash"

Comment: You can use java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() to detect when you component is in design mode

Comment: OK, that helps as a workaround, I guess. Thanks!